# Why I cannot create a new set in Aerospike?

Tags: c#, aerospike

I have an aerospike database server v5.3.0.3. it has multiple sets and I can add records to these sets. but when I am trying to add a new record to a not existing set I am getting this error:

> Error 22,1,30000,0,0,BB91DA09E565000 Server IP 3000: Operation not allowed at this time

I check the time of my cluster and they were fully synced.

Comment: Likely there is an associated warning being sent to the server logs. Could you post any warnings found in `/var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log`.

Comment: Are you at max limit of sets by any chance? 1023 sets max.

Comment: Thanks @pgupta but no... I have only 10sets on this db

Comment: Thank you @kporter I will check that log...

Comment: Are you adding a record to a null set and failing? Probably not - because you say you are unable to create a new set ... but just checking.

Comment: I figure it out. this was about TTL config on my aerospike server that was disabled and I was trying to add a record in a new set with ttl.